# "Number of Persons" instead of "Number of Person-years" in Stationary Population

Tags: self-study, demography, mortality

I have learnt that the life table function $_{n}L_x$ is the number of **person-years** lived by the cohort between ages $x$ and $x+n$.

But for stationary population, $_{n}L_x$ is defined as the number of persons in the population who at any moment are living within the age interval $(x, x+n)$.

I don't understand, for stationary population, why is $_{n}L_x$ number of persons , rather than number of **person-years**?

Comment: This looks like ti would fit in some other Stack Exchange site, but I am not sure which one.

Comment: @PeterFlom The question is on demography and I included this tag provided by  this site.

Comment: @Xi'an The question is on demography and I included this tag provided by this site.